# How to encode binary data for prediction input in Vertex AI

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have searched high and low across StackOverflow to solve this issue but either the answers are outdated (don't used TF 2.x) or are too complicated.

I have created a model as so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((128, 128, 3))
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3))(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(conv1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

I am saving the model as thus and want to host this SavedModel on Vertex AI Predictions.

```
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'placeholder_model')
```

Is there a different way I should save the model?

I want to use binary data encoded as `base64` strings as prediction inputs. The official documentation from [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-custom-models?hl=th#encoding-binary-data) for online predictions says:

> In your TensorFlow model code, you must name the aliases for your
> binary input and output tensors so that they end with '_bytes'.

My question is thus: How should export my `SavedModel` such that I can use `base64` strings to send requests for online predictions?

Comment: how do you get the binary data in your code? Can you share the acquisition code?

Comment: I don't think I got your question. Wouldn't I need to export the model in such a way that it accepts taking in `base64` strings as input?

Comment: From where the input come from in your training steps?

Comment: Ah I get it. To answer your first question I using JPEG images with shape (128, 128, 3) (and not strings) as the training input to the model. Once the model is trained I want to export it such that I can host it on Vertex AI Prediction such that it accepts taking in `base64` strings as input.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share ho do you export your model? Do you have a dedicated serving_input functions? Can you share more?

Comment: I have made edits wherein I have added how I am exporting my model.

Comment: Did you have a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save). You have to customize your input, your signature to correctly get and process the data that you send.

Comment: Yes I have taken a look at it. How do I customize my input and my signature to process the data?